# What's wrong with this solution to Putnam 2010 B1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Problem B1 from the 2010 Putnam asks if there exists a sequence $a_1,a_2,... \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots = m$ for every positive integer $m$.

I came up with a short solution, but it's wrong because the answer is supposed to be no. Here's my solution, can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Since $m2^{-n} > 0$, we can choose $a_n = (m2^{-n})^{1/m} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. Then,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^m = m\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = m$$

Am I missing something regarding convergence or the domain of $x^{1/m}$? Or is there something in the wording of the question that suggests that the sequence $a_1,a_2,...$ can't depend on $m$?

Comment: I don't understand your sequence.  $a_1$, say, has to be a real number, not a function of $m$.

Comment: As Lulu writes, your sequence is different for different $m.$ THAT is the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is asking whether there exists a *fixed* sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ such that $a_1^m + a_2^m + \cdots = m$ for *every* positive integer $m$.  You can't change the sequence for each $m$ -- else the problem would be easy, as you have found out.

Comment: Ah okay. If the quantifiers were moved, i.e. the question asked "For each positive integer $m$, does there exist a sequence $a_1,a_2,...$ such that <the sum of mth powers> equals m?" would this be a solution?

Comment: Yes, your solution would be correct for that question.